# Perl Hash of hash issue

Tags: algorithm, perl, hash

I have hash which looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '638047' => {
                    'commands' => 'perl nSWIFT/bin/tqtest.pl -var clist=',
                  },
      '638049' => {
                    'commands' => 'perl nSWIFT/bin/tqtest.pl-var clist=',
                  }
};
```

I want to create a directory such that the file name starts with hash values and it stores the numbers that are generated by running the commands given as `perl nswift/bin/tqtest.pl -var clist=`. The numbers should be stored in the same file as their key. For example:

```
'638047' -> '638050' and  '638049' -> '638051'
```

then it should be stored accordingly.

It have tried this but not getting there.

```
my %stat
my @qbsid_filename = keys %stat;
foreach (@qbsid_filename){
    open QBS, ">/root/qbsid/$_";
}
my $newqbsid, @files;
opendir (DIREC, '/root/qbsid') or die $!;
foreach my $qbsid ( keys %stat){
    my $cmd = $stat{$qbsid}->{commands};
    if ($cmd =~ m/perl(.*)/){
            $ex_cmd = $1;
    }
    $newqbsid = qx | perl $ex_cmd|;
}
close (DIREC);
```

I am not very good with algorithms. So, finding it difficult. 
Please inform me if I am going wrong somewhere or you need more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my %stat = { ... };

while (my ($qbsid_filename, $qbsid) = each %stat) {
    my $cmd = $qbsid->{commands};
    next unless $cmd =~ m/^perl/;

    open my $qbs, '>', "/root/qbsid/$qbsid_filename"
        or die "Cannot open $qbsid_filename: $!";

    open my $qbscmd, '-|', "$cmd"
        or die "Cannot execute $cmd: $!";
    while (<$qbscmd>) {
        print $qbs $_;
    }

    close ($qbscmd);
    close ($qbs);
}
```

Comment: What does '-|' do in the 'open my $qbsid, '-|', "$cmd"' statement? Thanks.

Comment: `open my $fh, '-|', "$cmd"` is the recommended way to say `open my $fh, "$cmd | "`, please check out `perldoc -f open` for further details.

Comment: It is not working as they is hash to hash reference.. But your just specify it for a single hash structure. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @deep It works for the data structure in your question.